# php code order being changed by server?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, echo

Someone explain to me what either the server or browser is doing here:

Integrated a wordpress blogs last 3 posts to display on home page of non wordpress site and simply was going to apply some inline CSS styling to the post:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<span style="color:blue;font-size:10px;">'.the_date().'</span><br>';
the_title(); 
the_excerpt();
endforeach;
?>
```

The styling does not occur because the echo line is being rendered by the browser/server/god/chaos or whatever AFTER the the_date() variable????

Actual rendered code:

```
<div id="blog-box">
November 11, 2013<span style="color:blue;font-size:10px;"></span><br>Hello world!<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>
</div>
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious but i don't get why this is not surrounding the date with the span code being echoed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_date()` has a built in `echo`.

Try this

```
echo '<span style="color:blue;font-size:10px;">';
the_date();
echo '</span><br>';
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked -- is the built in echo a PHP thing or is it being built in by wordpress as part of that function?

Comment: Its built in by wordpress. Most (maybe all) of the functions starting with the word `the_` has echo built into it. Just like `the_title()`, `the_excerpt()`, `the_content()` etc.